# Как обрабатывать много post запросов?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня есть страница, на которую приходит около 50 пост запросов, кажды йиз них обрабатывать очень сложно. Возможно ли на php сделать так, чтобы все post заганялись автоматически в массив? Предварительно обратываясь htmlspecialchars? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
$check13 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['check462']);
```

Я нашел решение, чтобы вывести циклом:

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
}
```

Но все понял имеют уникальное название (Answer1, Answer2, Question1, Question2) И я не могу понять, как все понля Answer1,2,3,4,-451 загнать в один массив, А все question,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 в другой, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не запросов,  а параметров в теле запроса.

Comment: Ну так сравнивай  param_name. Сразу позволить не мог?

Comment: парам нейм разные от 1 до 500

Comment: и Что? Проверяйте на содержание подстроки question или answer

Comment: Если бы я знал, как это проверить, я бы не писал вопрос умник.

Comment: ахаха, знать про метод strpos это быть умником

Answer (score 0):

Поля своей формы именуйте таким образом

```
<input name="check[1]" type="...
<input name="check[2]" type="...
...
<input name="check[462]" type="...
```

Перебор данных на стороне сервера делайте например так

```
if (isset($_POST['check']) && is_array($_POST['check'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $key => $value) {
        // тут ваша обработка $value по значению номера поля из $key
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно просто check[], номер не важен

Comment: @Alex78191, кто вам такое сказал? Номера ответов откуда будут браться?

Comment: по индексу в массиве

Comment: @Alex78191, так номера вопросов могут идти с разрывами. Те же 50 вопросов из 1000 вариантов выбранные случайным порядком :)